# Inequality with Euler's totient function

Tags: nt.number-theory

Numerical analysis of the first several hundred n suggests the following inequality:

$\varphi(3^n-2) \ge 2\cdot3^{n-1}$

Comment: Up to a small additive factor, your inequality says that if $p_1,\dots,p_k$ are distinct primes dividing a number of the form $3^n-2$, then $(1-p_1^{-1})\cdots(1-p_k^{-1})\ge2/3$. I suspect this is an instance of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120514 .

Comment: I can't see the connection to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120514?

Comment: The connection is only vague, just that some things are just naturally expected to be somewhat rare, a couple of hundreds is not much to test. In particular, you need an n such that 3^n - 2 is divisible by primes such that Emil J.'s product is less than 2/3. The only reason this is an issue at all is that you cannot have 2 and 3 for obvious reasons, neiter 11 nor 13, and also not 5 and 7 at the same time. So things get a bit large. Calculations got slightly too complex for me  for just doing them so, but with Emil J. idea and some calculation with  congruences one should find a counter ex.    

Comment: It seems not to hold for n=1.  Also, if you find a counterexample, both Emil's k and your n will be substantially larger than a thousand.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.02.07

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman: now while I might have been a bit too optimistic regarding how easy or not it is to find a counterexample but that one would need substantially more than a thousand different primes (the k) seems unlikely to me. Did you really mean this?  

Comment: I will back off on the size of k, as I have not done the calculations, and it may be possible to find a few small simultaneous prime divisors of 3^n - 2 that will do the job.  However, my experience with the product involving primes of (1 - 1/p) in perfect numbers and in bounding Jacobsthal's function have conditioned me to expect smallish examples to factor like primes whose numbers of digits grow at an exponential rate (so i^th prime has near 2^i decimal digits).  (Continued)  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.02.07

Comment: Excepting the cases n=1, 0, of course, I wager five cents that no counterexample will be found where k has only one decimal digit, seperately I wager 50 cents that  if there is a counterexample such an n will have at least 10 decimal digits, and  I will pay someone five dollars for a (clear demonstration of a) counterexample in which n has five or fewer decimal digits (but n has more than 1 decimal digit).  It may be likely that k has three decimal digits, but my gut tells me k will be larger.
Gerhard "Will Book Prime Number Races" Paseman, 2013.02.07

Comment: In some sense the question is settled by Peter Mueller's answer but some general remarks follwoing up on Gerhard Paseman's comment and to explain how (I assume) the example was found: I consider it as misleading to think about this problem as finding some n such that 3^n - 2 has certain properties. It is relatively easy (if one does not go really large) to decide when for some given prime $p$ *there is* some $n$ such that $3^n-2$ is divisible by $p$ and also to find it (it works always if $3$ is primitive root mod $p$). Also one gets an entire coset mod $p$. cont.      

Comment: cont. The number of primes for which 3 is a primitive root is/should be a nonsmall (about a third) constant fraction of all primes (Artin conj).
So this is not too restrictive regarding the primes one can take. However, in addition (and realizing this made me stop my handcomputations) there is an issue now finding a common solution of the different congruence mod (p-1) for the various primes (excluding taking 5 and 7 together for example). So that in addition one can only take primes where the indices of $2$ base $3$ are somehow compatible. 


Comment: Argh! The last mod p in the first comment should be p−1. If only it where p, the thing would be quite a bit simpler. ;) Further clarfification: my "has certain properties" is quite unspecific, what I mean is one should not test for the n and see if 3^n - 2 somehow factors, but *construct* the n such that the divisibilty is guaranteed.

Comment: Actually, you don’t need 3 to be a primitive root, only that the order of 2 mod $p$ divides the order of 3. (E.g., 3 is not a primitive root modulo 23, 47, 71, 97 in Peter Mueller’s solution.) Each such prime corresponds to a constraint on $n$ which is a congruence modulo the order of 3. By a version of the Chinese remainder theorem, a set of such constraints is solvable iff they are pairwise compatible in the sense that they induce the same congruence modulo their gcd.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek: yes, I did not want to claim  that one *needs* 3 is a primitive root. The "always" might not be the best choice of word to convey that I meant this as sufficient property not as characterization, but this was the intent of adding "always". Thanks for clarifiying this.  

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take $n=382315009082231724951830011$. Then $3^n-2$ is divisible by the primes $5, 19, 23, 47, 71, 97, 149, 167, 173, 263, 359, 383, 389, 461, 479, 503, 557$. Furthermore, $\varphi(3^n-2)<2/3\cdot(3^n-2)<2\cdot 3^{n-1}$.

The following Sage code verifies this examples. I believe that this is close to a minimal counterexample.

```
sage: n=382315009082231724951830011
sage: l=[5, 19, 23, 47, 71, 97, 149, 167, 173, 263, 359, 383, 389, 461, 479, 503, 557]
sage: set(3.powermod(n,p) for p in l)
set([2])
sage: prod(1-1/p for p in l).n()
0.666250824539016
```

As there are some speculations about how to find such an example, here is the (not really clever) Sage code which greedily collects the congruences for $n$ which do not contradict each other:

```
p,n,Q = 5,3,4
lp = [p]
s = 1-1/p
while True:
    p=p.next_prime()
    e=IntegerModRing(p)(3).multiplicative_order()
    l=[z for z in [1..e-1] if 3.powermod(z,p) == 2]
    if len(l) == 0:
        continue
    b=l[0]
    if (b-n) % e.gcd(Q) != 0:
        continue
    QQ=Q.lcm(e)
    n=CRT_list([n,b],[Q,e]) % QQ
    Q=QQ
    s*=(1-1/p)
    lp.append(p)
    print p,s.n()
    if 2/3>s:
        print n,lp
        break
```

Comment: I would like the answer more if I had a good lower bound on k, the number of distinct prime factors of the counterexample.  Can you at least trial divide by candidates up to 3^20 or even perhaps 3^50 to get an idea?  Gerhard "Would Be Ever So Grateful" Paseman, 2013.02.07

Comment: Thanks for this answer! After I initially saw the question I got quite curious what would be the outcome. Did you also try what happens if you start with 7 insted of 5? I would be quite curious how it compares. ps for Gerhard Paseman: regarding the k again, it occurs to me we were also talking about somewhat different things (which is my fault) but to *me* the k here is seventeen, if I counted right in any case the number of primes one had to take into account. But sure the 'rest' seems huge so there might be quite a few additional factors 'hiding'. 

Comment: @Gerhard: I believe there is no way to factor $3^n-2$, this number has more that $10^{26}$ decimal digits! @quid: Indeed, if one starts with $7$, things look quite differently. Up to $p<70000$, this greedy approach yields $425$ compatible primes, starting with $7, 17, 23, 47, 71, 167,\ldots$, yet the product of the $1-1/p$ for these primes is still bigger than $0.692$.

Comment: Ah.  We are, and I mistook Emil's k for omega(n).  My mistake.  Indeed Emil's k can be two digits.  My k is omega(n), and for every such counterexample, my gut says my k has more than two digits.  Peter, I was hoping you would compute it mod p for a few million choice primes p, but it is not as important now.  Gerhard "Not Quite The Omega Man" Paseman, 2013.02.07

Comment: @Peter Mueller: thank you for this additional information. I'd guessed the situations are more similar. 