# Impossibility of certain carmichael numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

T. Wright http://www.math.jhu.edu/~wright/carmichael.pdf proves that $lcm ((p_1-1),(p_2-1),...)$ over the prime factors of a carmichael number cannot be of the form $2^s$

How to prove that carmichael numbers cannot be of the form $3^s-2$

Comment: Is your first sentence at all related to your question?

Comment: From the first sentence it follows that there are no Charmichael numbers of the form $2^s+1$. The question is about a similar statement for powers of $3$. This might be true,
although we have seen counterexamples to questions of type $3^s-2$ - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121066/inequality-with-eulers-totient-function