# Partial sums of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

$2+3+5+7+11+13...$ is clearly the sum of the primes.

Now I consider partial sums such:

$2+3+5+7+11=28$ which is divisible by $7$

My question is:

are there infinitely many partial sums such that:

$p_1+p_2+p_3+...+p_{k}+p_{k+1}=m*p_{k}?$ with $m$ some positive integer? With Pari/gp apparently up to 10^10 there are only two examples $7$=$p_k$ and $8263=p_k$. Heuristically do you think that infinitely many such partial sums should exist? Note: 7 and 8263 are both primes belonging to primes on the left side of the triangle formed by listing successively the prime numbers in a triangular grid. See https://oeis.org/A078721
Note in both cases $2+3+5+7=17$ is prime and $2+3+5+...+p_{1036}=3974497$ is prime. I note that $17$ and $3974497$ are primes of the form $4s+1$, whereas $p_4=7$ and $p_{1036}=8263$ are primes of the form $6s+1$.
$7$ and $8263$ are primes such that starting from the right, the odd positioned digits are prime and the even positioned digits are composite. But also $5$ and $8243$ which are the previous primes have this property. No other prime of this type found below $10^{12}$
I noticed that 7! has 4 digits where 4 is a palindrome. 8263! has 28782 digits where 28782 is a palindrome.

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120511/why-do-primes-dislike-dividing-the-sum-of-all-the-preceding-primes. Also crossposted on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161810/23571113 (please don't do this anymore).

Comment: @Alex M.@Mark Fischler the heuristic is the same for primes p(n) dividing the sum of primes up to p(n+1) and for primes p(n) dividing the sum of primes up to p(n). But it seems that in the first case primes are rarer. Why?

Comment: The second solution ($8263$) has some amazing properties : The sum of its digits, the sum of the squares of its digits and the sum of the fifth powers of its digits are prime as well as $$8^8+2^2+6^6+3^3$$

Comment: @Peter $8+2+6+3=19$. $8263+19-1=91^2$ where 91 is 19 reversed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do primes dislike dividing the sum of all the preceding primes?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120511/why-do-primes-dislike-dividing-the-sum-of-all-the-preceding-primes)

Comment: Seven edits in the last 12 hours.

Comment: Now up to Version 13.

Comment: $7$ is a Mersenne prime. $8263$ is the sum of five Mersenne primes $17$+$17$+$31$+$8191$+$31$+$7$.

Comment: I find these frequent edits go against the purpose of this forum.  If you want to record frequent observations on a daily basis (whether they are significant or not), start a blog.  You have asked a main question and gotten a reasonable answer; now move on.  The numerology associated with the problem does not belong here. Next week, if you find a third prime satisfying the relations, you can report that here. Gerhard "Know When To Fold 'Em" Paseman, 2019.03.28.

Comment: Version 16. Please, homunc, give it a rest.

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman 7 is the 4th prime, 8263 is the 1036th prime. 7/7(sum of digits of 7)=1 and 4# has 1 digit. 8263/19(sum of digits of 8263) is truncated equal to 434...1036# has 434 digits where # is primorial function

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP persists in these edits. (I agree with GP and GM)

Comment: @YemonChoi While the editing was annoying, it does seem to have stopped (last edit 5 days ago).

Answer (score 17):

You asked for a heuristic answer.

There is an heuristic argument that infinitely many such partial sums should exist.  Consider $P(k)$, an heuristic estimate of the probability that the partial sum of the first $k+1$ primes would be divisible by $p_k$.  Now $$p_k \sim k \log k$$ and if only random chance were involved,  $$P(k) \approx \frac1{p_k}  \sim \frac1{k \log k}$$

In that case, the expected number of primes with the property you want would be something like
$$\int_2^\infty \frac1{x \log x}\,dx$$
and that integral diverges to infinity.

The reason it seems so rare is that the rate of divergence is like $\log(\log x)$ and while that function goes to infinity, "nobody ever sees it do so."

On the other hand, **proving** that there an infinite number of such values of $k$ (in the same sense that Euclid's argument proves there is no last prime) is probably quite difficult.  And if the conjecture that there are an infinite number of such values of $k$ turned out to be false,  **proving** that some particular $k$ is the last one with this property would seem to be even harder.

Comment: Note this answer is essentially the same as David Speyer's in the question linked to in the comment by @Alex M. above.

Comment: "nobody ever sees it do so." - you made my day!